# delegatin assertion

Tags: c++, debugging, assertion

Hi I want to improve my math library,

when I compute lenght of something I do

```
assert( !equal(len,0.0));
const f32 invsqrt = 1.0/sqrt(len);
X*= invsqrt;
Y*= invsqrt;
Z*= invsqrt;
```

this code is nice and if I do wrongly the division by zero the code breaks

"Runtime has requested to break application at line .. Vector.h line 88"

This is nice, but I want to do better, I want to show where error is REALLY.

So instead of showing "vector.h" and line 88 I want to show "main.cpp" "line 15" (if the getLength function is called at line 15 in main).

Vector is header only, so I think that achieving that is possible (that's just a feeling).. but how?

Thanks in advance. I hope you can see how usefull would be doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's where the code is, so that where it will break.

I think what you mean is to see the call stack.
In visual studio it's at: **Debug -> Windows -> Call Stack**.

The call stack can show you how you got to that line of code (which function were called in the work flow)

Comment: yes, but assume final user has GCC by command line and so can't look at stack easily like when using an IDE. I was guessing if is possible show the FILE and LINE at an immediatly upper level without looking at stack, would be interesting investigating that.

Comment: @DarioOO It's perfectly reasonable to assume that programmers are comfortable using the tools of their choice. In your example, that they know their way around gdb.

Comment: yes but there's still one case in wich is usefull. the release: the user will just see his application crashing at "Vector.h" while obviously the error is elsewhere. Having reporter the correct line can help support staff to catch the bug, and usually users do not have a debugger